# Filter values from strings using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter a value from a string using regular expressions, **for example** filtering out the URL from a `<a href=""/>` tag.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
```

I looked through the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library and the regexp that should match the string should be

```
r'<a href="(.*)">'
```

Now what's the best way to save this value into a variable?

Comment: the best way is to use an html parser instead of regex

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use an html parsing library such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Check out BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I know about libs like BeautifulSoup for doing that but I'd like to start from scratch because the href tag is only a example and not my actual problem

Comment: @tehmisvh: If parsing html is not your actual goal and just a silly example, I recommend that you edit your question to make this very clear in bold letters, in order to avoid a lot of downvotes and comments...

Comment: Damn what part of “for example” don’t people understand? +1 for good question.

Comment: @daknøk If we take the *for example* at face value, the question is just *how do I filter a value from a string using regular expressions?* That question is [too widely scoped](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), IMO.

Comment: @kojiro the question was about getting the group out of the match (the `(.*)` part), not about extracting values in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't parse html with regex, but since you said that is only an example...
If you expect to always find a match:

```
try:
    foo = re.search(r'<a href="(.*)">', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    foo = None
```

If you don't know if it will match:

```
match = re.search(r'<a href="(.*)">', text)
if match:
    foo = match.group(1)
else:
    foo = None
```

Comment: `re.search` and `re.match` return `None` if no match is found.  It's safer to test if the result of `re.search` is not None and then get the group...

Comment: @mgilson: Good point, I expanded the answer to cover this. Do you agree with the way I did it here?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good.  I just figured that if OP didn't know about `.group` then maybe a little more explanation would be helpful. (+1)